# SqlDataReader - How to convert the current row to a dictionary

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sqldatareader

Is there an easy way to convert all the columns of the current row of a SqlDataReader to a dictionary?

```
using (SqlDataReader opReader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
// Convert the current row to a dictionary
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
return Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                 .ToDictionary(reader.GetName, reader.GetValue);
```

Comment: Your response looks interesting, but I need it in VB.NET, and I don't know how to translate the last part - .ToDictionary(reader.GetName, reader.GetValue). Any sugegstion? Thanks

Comment: @bzamfir: You need `AddressOf`.

Comment: I'm wary of jumping on the linq-is-everything bandwagon but this is splendid.

Comment: This is the best solution put forward so far

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842651/convert-datareader-to-dictionary

Comment: a m aaaaa zing ly clever.

Comment: I'm 8.5 years post this original post, and I'm here to say THANK YOU! This is beautiful.

Answer (score 28):

Easier than this?:

```
// Need to read the row in, usually in a while ( opReader.Read ) {} loop...
opReader.Read();

// Convert current row into a dictionary
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
for( int lp = 0 ; lp < opReader.FieldCount ; lp++ ) {
    dict.Add(opReader.GetName(lp), opReader.GetValue(lp));
}
```

I'm still not sure why you would need this particular transformation from one type of collection to another.

Comment: As an answer to your question: if one needs to cache the results, it seems wiser to cache the dictionary copy. Otherwise you end up with a lot of open readers

Comment: @Toad One can use a DataTable if you want to cache the results.  `MyDataTable.Load(dr);`

Comment: @CadeRoux a DataTable would read the entire result set instead of a single row no?

Comment: @CadeRoux Saving to a Dictionary is like 4-5 times faster than a DataTable. One test: http://lauteikkehn.blogspot.ro/2012/03/datatable-vs-list.html

Comment: I don't understand why, instead of simply answering, people inquire "why are you doing this? or why are you asking this?" We do not know what the actual scenario for which somebody asks the question

Answer (score 6):

I came across this question on 3/9/2016 and ended up using the answer provided by SLaks. However, I needed to slightly modify it to:

```
dataRowDictionary = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).ToDictionary(i => reader.GetName(i), i=> reader.GetValue(i).ToString());
```

I found guidance from this StackOverflow question: [convert dataReader to Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842651/convert-datareader-to-dictionary)

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was trying to do. It also converts nulls to empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

GetValues method accepts & puts in, all the values in a 1D array.
Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

It's already an `IDataRecord`.

That should give you just about the same access (by key) as a dictionary.  Since rows don't typically have more than a few handfuls of columns, the performance of the lookups shouldn't be that different.  The only important difference is the type of the "payload", and even there your dictionary would have to use object for the value type, so I give the edge to IDataRecord.

Comment: This is useful when you'd like the result of a query to be available after you've freed up the connection. DataReader objects are intrinsically tied to the connection they were created with.