# convert dataReader to Dictionary

Tags: linq, dictionary, datareader

I tried to use LINQ to convert one row to Dictionary (fieldName -> fieldValue)

```
return Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                 .ToDictionary<string, object>(reader.GetName, reader.GetValue);
```

but I received error message:

Instance argument: cannot convert from `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'`

How to correct this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/4286071/292060

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
return Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
                 .ToDictionary(
                     i => reader.GetName(i),
                     i => reader.GetValue(i));
```

Comment: Isn't this doing exactly the same as the statement of the OP? Why would this not yield the same error?