# C# SQL to dictionary

Tags: c#, php, t-sql

When I'm quering in PHP something like that:

```
SELECT `ID`, `Name`, `EmailAddress` FROM `Accounts` WHERE `ID` = {$id}
```

I will return the result something in this sturcture:

```
{
    "ID":1,
    "EmailAddress":"banana@scale.com",
    "Name":"Joseph"
}
```

When I'm quering in C# like that:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [ID], [Name], [EmailAddress] FROM [Accounts] WHERE [ID] = @ID", con);

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", id.ToString()));


SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

It'll return something in this sturcture:

```
(
    0 : 1,
    1 : "Joseph",
    2 : "banana@scale.com"
)
```

My question is : how can I make the same sturcture in c#?

Comment: You mean like a hashmap/dictionary? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912948/sqldatareader-how-to-convert-the-current-row-to-a-dictionary

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464883/how-can-i-easily-convert-datareader-to-listt

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a valid JSON that you have to look at [Newtonsoft JSON library](http://james.newtonking.com/json)

Use JsonConvert class:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObjectToSerializeToJSON);
```